# Prevent TinyMCE from converting linebreaks

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, wysiwyg, umbraco

I want to prevent TinyMCE from converting linebreaks (pasted from notepad for example) into `<br>`'s.
Thats because I want to post code snippets inside `<pre>` tags, and I don't want to have `<br>`'s in there.

I already tried several TinyMCE settings in the config without success:

```
force_p_newlines : false,
force_br_newlines : false,
remove_linebreaks : false,
convert_newlines_to_brs : false
```

After submiting the content TinyMCE still converts all of my linebreaks.
I'm using TinyMCE 3 with umbraco CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. It seems to be an Firefox/TinyMCE related bug.
The described symptoms only appear when using Firefox. 
Tested Internet Explorer 8 and Opera 9 and it works.